# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class mcs_subdomain could not be converted to string in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

please help.

There is a PHP Error Message that comes from a Plugin.

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Object of class mcs_subdomain could not be converted to string

```
public function bloginfo_url($output, $show ) {

    if('url' == $show)
        return $this->$this->subdomain_home;
    
    if( $show == 'rdf_url' || $show == 'rss_url' || $show == 'rss2_url' || $show == 'atom_url') {
        return $this->replace_to_subdomain_link( $this->subdomain->slug, $output );
    }
        
    return $output;
}
```

this code error "return $this->$this->subdomain_home;"

How to Fix.

Comment: Seems that it should be ```return $this->subdomain_home;``` So remove "$this->"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return $this->subdomain_home;`

Just remove extra "$this->"

Comment: @CilacapInfoTV if this is the answer please check the V sign on the answer. Thanks.